# Use table name as a function parameter

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating a function, the role of this function is to check if there is data in the specified table or not.

**Function**

```
function check_empty_table($tablename, $response) {

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename");

 if(empty($result)){
  $response = '';
  return $response; 
  }

 if(!empty($result)){
 $response = $result;
 return $response; 
 }

}
```

Here I am using the function with 'variables' as a table name ..

```
check_empty_table('variables', $response);
$variables = $response;
echo '<select name="' . $id . '" id="' . $id . '" class="select">';
echo '<option value="">Variable Name</option>';
foreach ( $variables as $variable ){
echo '<option' . selected( esc_attr( $meta ), $variable->name, false ) . ' value="' . $variable->name . '">' . $variable->name . '</option>';
                         }
echo '</select><br />' . $desc;
```

I am not sure which is this not working, at the end of it the $response returns empty even if there is data in the table ..

Thanks ..

Comment: what do you mean "not working", what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to pass $response by reference (`&$response`), or simply do:

```
$variables = check_empty_table('variables', $response);
```

---

### Passing by reference explanation

By passing the response parameter by reference (`function check_empty_table($tablename, &$response) {...`, note the `&`), the second parameter in the function call will get its value causing the code to still work. It might be confusing because the variables inside the function and outside of it have the same name, so here is a super-simple example:

```
function f(&$ref) {
    return ++$ref;
}

$a = 1;
$a = f($a); // $a is now 2, of course
f($a);      // no assignment, but what's the value of $a now?
```

Comment: $response should not be there at all, not used in the function.

Comment: @Dagon, agreed... unless it's passed by reference.

Comment: not used in the function, he is just a little confused

Comment: @Dagon, I agree that it might not be a good idea to bother him with this, but if you change the function to `function check_empty_table($tablename, &$response) {`, the `$response` variable (outside the function) would get the value of the `$response` from inside it... Possibly, I made it more confusing now.

Comment: Well actually you did :d , but I got the point where you suggested to use &$response either than $response. It worked though, the solution by shomz.

Comment: Haha, sorry, @Fahad. I tried to explain it in my update.

Comment: I think the value of $a would be 3 at the end, am I correct ?

Comment: @FahadSohail Yes, Sir! :)